# Qt OpenGL Widget Not Showing Triangles Until Resized

Tags: qt, opengl

I am new to programing OpenGL and fairly new to Qt. Following a tutorial, I have used the following code to create two triangles in my OpenGL Widget:

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::initializeGL() {
    qDebug("initializing");

    GLfloat verticies[] = {
        +0.0f, +0.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f,
        -1.0f, +1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        +1.0f, -1.0f
    };

    GLuint vertexBufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticies), verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    GLushort indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 3, 4
    };

    GLuint indexBufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

void MainWindow::paintGL() {
    qDebug("painting");

    //glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

The strange this is that this code works perfectly, but only shows up if I resize the window:

Before resize:
[image: Before resize]

After resize:
[image: After resize]

Both `initializing` and `painting` are outputted to the console before the resize so they are being called.

What about the resize causes the triangles to show?

I am using Mac OSX (Mavericks) if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

By default, auto swapping should be on, that should take care of updating the screen after PaintGL. Just to be sure, can you do a `swapBuffers()` call before leaving PaintGL ?

Comment: I added the line `swapBuffers();` to the end of `paintGL`. Same behavior.

Answer (score -1):

It might be useful to use

```
glViewPort(0, 0, width(), height());
```